# Equivalence of different criteria for Lebesgue measurability

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a set. Two different criteria for Lebesgue measurability of $E$ is given by:

$(i)$ (Outer approximation by open) For every $\epsilon>0$, one can contain $E$ in an open set $U$ with $m^*(U \setminus E) \leq \epsilon$.

$(ii)$ (Almost open) For every $\epsilon>0$, one can find an open set $U$ such that $m^*(U \Delta E) \leq \epsilon$.

The problem is to show the equivalence of these two statements. Now, $(i) \Rightarrow (ii)$ is of course trivial. But I'm having some difficulty in showing $(ii) \Rightarrow (i)$.

Given that, for every $\epsilon>0$, one can find an open set $U$ such that $m^*(U \Delta E) \leq \epsilon$, how can I find an open set $V$, containing $E$ with $m^*(V \setminus E) \leq \epsilon ~??$

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take an open set $U$ such that $m^*(U\Delta E)\leq \epsilon/4$.

This tells you that $m^*(U-E)< \epsilon/4$ and $m^*(E-U)<\epsilon/4$.

Now, since $m^*(E-U)<\epsilon/4$ we can find a countable union of intervals $B$ such that $m^*(B)<2\epsilon/4$ and $(E-U)\subseteq B$. We can change each interval into an open interval by enlarging slightly (use the geometric series) to get an open set $D$ such that $m^*(D)<3\epsilon/4$ and $(E\setminus U)\subseteq D$.

We propose the set $U\cup D$ as the required open set. Clearly it contains $E$, as $D$ contains $E\setminus U$.

Now, what about $\mu^*( (U\cup D) \setminus E)$?

We have $\mu^*( (U\cup D) \setminus E)\leq \mu^*(U-E)+ \mu^*(D-E)\leq \epsilon$

Comment: I'm working in $\mathbb{R}^d$ set-up, so I'm assuming that "intervals" in your solution will be "boxes". Now I have one question. (I'm sure it's obvious but still I want to clarify it). $E \setminus U$ is a set with arbitrarily small (but positive!) Lebesgue outer measure, that's all we know about it! What is a rigorous argument to show that we can efficiently contain it within countable union of boxes?

Comment: what is your definition for the outer measure? It is usally the infimum over all of the sums of measures of the countable covers of the set (with elements inside the ring) You may want to check out this pdf for example: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~westra/caratheodory.pdf

Comment: Yes, that helps! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

To show (ii)$\implies$ (i), assume $\neg$ (i) and prove $\neg$ (ii).

Let $r>0$ such  that $m^*(U$ \ $E)>r$ whenever $U$ is open and $U\supset E.$  Suppose by contradiction  there is open $V$ with $m^*(V \Delta E  )<r/4.$

Let $W$ be open with $W\supset E$ \ $V$ and $m^*(W)<m^*(E$ \ $V)+ r/4.$

Then $W\cup V \supset E$ so $$r<m^*((W\cup V) \backslash E)=$$    $$=m^*((W \backslash E)\cup (V \backslash E))\leq$$    $$\leq  m^*(W \backslash E)+m^*(V \backslash E)\leq$$    $$\leq  m^*(W )+m^*(V \Delta E)<$$    $$<  [m^*(E \backslash V)+r/4] +[r/4]\leq$$    $$\leq m^*( E \Delta V)+r/2 <$$ $$<r/4+r/2<r $$ implying $r<r.$